# search a column if a string exists in mysql (reverse of match against)

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I'm having a column in a table with specific words and want to search a long string for any matches and return the row(s). Something like -

```
select * from filter_names where match('some long text') against (filter_string);
```

I cannot do so unfortunately because i think it's not possible with mysql as stated here -

[MySQL MATCH() AGAINST() with reversed parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283863/mysql-match-against-with-reversed-parameters)

But it's an answer from 2016 i thought maybe there's something out there in 2020.

Hope for the best...

Comment: Nothing added. You may create a table temporarily (I look ReM for does temporary table may have FTI, but found nothing), create FT index over it, then use MATCH .. AGAINST.

Comment: @Akina i have to create a temporary table with a column which has all the words in my haystack string and then simply do a left join select query?

Comment: Yes. Now `'some long text'` is not string literal but the value for a column in a table.